# How to create a bullet list from parsed dynamic object

Tags: html, json, typescript, vue.js

So I have a JSON string `foo_json_string`:

```
[{"foo_name":"foo_value"},{"foo_name1":"foo_value1"}]
```

that I want to parse and show as HTML list.

I used the following approach:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in JSON.parse(foo_json_string)" v-bind:key="item.id">
    {{`${item.name} = ${item.value}`}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

This doesn't work. Most likely because `item.name` and `item.value` don't exist but I am not sure how to fix that. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the result??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you mean like this ?

```js
var respond = [{"foo_name":"foo_value"},{"foo_name1":"foo_value1"}];

$.each(respond, function(k, v){
  console.log(v);
  $.each(v, function(k1, v1){
    $('#out').append('<li>'+v1+'</li>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="out"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `key` of the parsed `Object`. Use `Object.keys()` method for getting the key. There is the working snippet below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo_json_string: '[{"foo_name":"foo_value"},{"foo_name1":"foo_value1"}]',
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="item in JSON.parse(foo_json_string)">
    <li v-for="key in Object.keys(item)">
      {{`${key} = ${item[key]}`}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```